# Unresponsive harddrive unlock screen after kernel upgrader 4.4 -> 4.8

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel, lvm

I have this strange error after upgrading my kernel from 4.4 to 4.8. I have an encrypted harddrive and the unlock screen only responds when I boot in 4.4. Whenever I choose 4.8 the unlock-screen is completely unresponsive.

It is not critical for me to move to 4.8, but I'd really like the better battery-performance gained by the upgrade.

Any suggestions as to how I can fix this? FYI, I installed the kernel with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.8.0-34-generic linux-headers-4.8.0-34 linux-headers-4.8.0-34-generic --fix-missing
```

Comment: I notice that you have not installed the corresponding `linux-image-extra`...

Comment: Hmmm, perheps i've forgotten that. Will retry with that package as well

Answer (score 0):

If anybody stumbles past this question, my solution ended up being installing kernel 4.9 instead. Not sure what is wrong in 4.8, but I see no issues yet running 4.9 instead.

My computer is a Dell XPS 9550, if that's any help

Comment: Kernel 4.9 is unsupported and should not be installed unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: I haven't had any issues with it. Which kernel is the newest supported one?

Comment: Depends on your version of Ubuntu; the question is tagged 14.04 but if you are really on 14.04, it's no wonder you can't get kernel 4.8 to work because it's not supported either, and the latest supported one is 4.4.

Comment: And for that matter, in order to instal kernel 4.8 with Apt on 14.04, you need to add the 16.04 repositories, which is a bad idea since you clearly don't know what you are doing. If you are on 14.04 and want a newer kernel than 4.4, upgrade to 16.04.

Comment: Shoot, I am on 16.04, so this topic should probably be moved. I switched to 4.8 and my graphics card is now recognized, which I found out it wasn't on 4.9. Probably best to stay on 4.8 then :) Thanks alot for your input!